# Let $F$ be a field, and let $f(x)\in F[x]$ be a polynomial. Prove that$ f(x) / (x-a)^k (x-b)^l$ can be expressed in the following way.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field, and let $f(x)\in F[x]$ be a polynomial. Prove that $f(x) / (x-a)^k (x-b)^l$ ( where $a,b\in F$ and $k,l\in Z+$) can be expressed as

$h(x) + r(x)/(x-a)^k + s(x)/(x-b)^l$ where $deg (r)< k$ and $deg(s) < l$, and $h,r,s\in F[x]$.

My attempt : As $F$ is a field, $F[x]$ is a Euclidean domain, so the division algorithm holds with $N(f) = deg (f) + 1$ with the convention $deg (0) = -1$.

Then, we can write $f(x) = A(x)(x-a)^k + r(x)$ with $deg (r) < k$, so for $x=/=a$, we divide by $(x-a)^k$ to get $f(x)/(x-a)^k = A(x) + r(x)/(x-a)^k$.

I can do the same thing for $(x-b)^l$. Now, basically, I wanna show that

$f(x) = h(x)(x-a)^k(x-b)^l + r(x)(x-b)^l + s(x)(x-a)^k$ with $deg (r)<k$ and $deg(s)<l$.

How do I get an expression of this form from the two expressions I already have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $F[x]$ is a Euclidean domain, and since $(x-a)^k$ and $(x-b)^l$ are relatively prime, we can write $1=p(x)(x-a)^k + q(x)(x-b)^l$  for some $p$ and $q$ in $F[x]$ (say by the Euclidean algorithm, or however you want to do this). Then
$$\frac{f(x)}{(x-a)^k(x-b)^l} = \frac{f(x)p(x)(x-a)^k + f(x)q(x)(x-b)^l}{(x-a)^k(x-b)^l} = \frac{f(x)p(x)}{(x-b)^l} + \frac{f(x)q(x)}{(x-a)^k}. $$
Then use the division algorithm on both fractions to get this into your desired form.

Comment: How $\text{deg}\,\, f(x)p(x) < l$, and $\text{deg}\,\, f(x)q(x) < k$?

Comment: They're not, that's why I said use division algorithm to get it into the desired form. I.e. divide $f(x)p(x)$ by $(x-b)^l$ to get some whole polynomial and a remainder with degree less than $l$. Similarly for $f(x)q(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do we prove that $(x-a)^k$ and $(x-b)^l$ are relatively prime? Also, are there any general tips for problems like these? Whenever i look at the solution it's rather simple, but it's rare for me to actually get it..

Comment: I mean, $(x-a)$ and $(x-b)$ are both prime/irreducible, since they're linear polynomials, and $a\ne b$ since otherwise the statement is false, so by unique factorization, $(x-a)^k$ and $(x-b)^l$ are relatively prime, since they share no common prime factors. As for tips, well, in this case, I just noticed it looked a lot like partial fractions from calculus, and it occurred to me that that often works by taking a partial fraction decomposition of 1/(your denominator).

Comment: So I'm not sure if I have a general tip, tho it's always nice to remember that you can write the gcd of $x$ and $y$ elements as $ax+by$ for some $a$ and $b$ when you're working in a PID/Euclidean domain.

Comment: Thanks! So if it weren't a euclidean domain, then they may not have been relatively prime? Or does the notion of primality become obscure in non-euclidean domains? Lastly, how do we do know that in $(x-a)^k$, each individual $x-a$ is prime?

Comment: Ok so that's quite a few questions. Let me try to answer them, tho I think you may be better served by asking a new question rather than asking in the comments. Firstly, Euclidean domains are unique factorization domains. In unique factorization domains, we can give a straightforward notion of greatest common divisor/relatively prime, and it means that the two elements of the ring share no common factors other than invertible elts. Primality is well defined in commutative domains. $p$ is prime if $p\mid ab$ implies either $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$. Lastly $(x-a)$ is irreducible, and hence prime.